# Adding sitewide JS file in module

Tags: 7, hooks, javascript

I have a module that will provide a dropdown when creating a new block. Selecting either none, option 1 or option 2 will add a corresponding class to that block. That class will be targeted by a small (>4kb) jquery file. The file needs to be able to access every page since blocks can be put anywhere on the site.

I have seen multiple methods of adding JS files to websites, including editing the theme .info file. What is the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do? If the info file is the best way to go, is there a way to programmatically add the JS file to the info file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file to a theme's or module's .info file using `scripts[]`:

```
scripts[] = js/my-script.js
```

The path should be relative to your module root.

See also [Writing theme .info files](https://drupal.org/node/171205) and [Writing module .info files](https://drupal.org/node/542202).

Comment: I know I can do that, but I want to be able to have it completely taken care of upon the module being enabled. Any Joe Schmoe should be able to enable this module, and not have to modify the .info file. Is there a way I can do this without having to manually add the script?

Comment: You are not adding any script. With that line you tell drupal your module needs that file in every page.

Comment: @mattcoker That's exactly what that `scripts[]` line does. When the module is enabled, Drupal reads its .info file and finds the `scripts[]` line, and then automatically includes the script on every single page.

Comment: My apologies. I thought you meant specifically adding that to my theme .info file. I totally understand now.